# Extract cell means from ANOVA result and plot them

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Is it possible to extract the cell means from an ANOVA result so one can plot them?  I can extract the cell means using Part but I am not able to plot that information using ListPlot.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Use the following as an example...

```
Needs["ANOVA`"];
ANOVA[{
       {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, 
       {2, 1, 5}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 4}, {2, 2, 2}}
      }, {x, y}, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to see what you are dealing with specifically?

Comment: Will that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Needs["ANOVA`"]

anovaresults = 
  ANOVA[{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 5}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 2, 4}, {2, 2, 2}}, {x, y}, {x, y}];
```

To plot all of them:

```
ListPlot[anovaresults[[2, 2, 1, All, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... or only the ones corresponding to `x[1], x[2], y[1], y[2]`:

```
ListPlot[anovaresults[[2, 2, 1, 2 ;;, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is awesome.  thank you.  I got to the [2,2,1] level but didn't know how to "drill" down to the actual values like you did.

Comment: @StevenAnderson Glad it helps! Thanks for the accept as well.

Comment: @StevenAnderson Also, note that you can get the list of `CellMeans` for further manipulations by `First[CellMeans /.ANOVA[...]]`.

Comment: @yohbs - thank you.